IndexError: Trying to locate names followed by their email address
df1
kate@gmail.com
james@gmail.com
john@gmail.com
ryan@gmail.com

df2
      Email             Name   
      kate@gmail.com    Kate       
      james@gmail.com   James    
      john@gmail.com    John
      ryan@gmail.com    Ryan

I'm trying to pull their unique names (df2) based on the email list (df1) that is provided without creating another dataframe. Rather, I would just like a list.
I tried to use below script to pull unique names
for x in df1:
    df2.loc[df2['Email']==x]['Name'].unique()[0]

This results in an index error saying:

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

I'm trying to locate unique values, but keep getting an indexerror. How can I fix this issue?

try df2[df2['Email'].isin(df1)]['Name'].unique()?

IIUC, you want to use map with a pd.Series created by df2 with email as index and name as values:
create df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Email': {0: 'kate@gmail.com',
  1: 'james@gmail.com',
  2: 'john@gmail.com',
  3: 'ryan@gmail.com'},
 'Name': {0: 'Kate', 1: 'James', 2: 'John', 3: 'Ryan'}})

create df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3},
 'Email': {0: 'kate@gmail.com',
  1: 'james@gmail.com',
  2: 'john@gmail.com',
  3: 'ryan@gmail.com'},
 'Name': {0: 'Kate', 1: 'James', 2: 'John', 3: 'Ryan'}})

Use map to get names in df1:
df1['Name'] = df1['Email'].map(df2.set_index('Email')['Name'])
print(df1)

Output:
             Email   Name
0   kate@gmail.com   Kate
1  james@gmail.com  James
2   john@gmail.com   John
3   ryan@gmail.com   Ryan

